# Loops con listas en Python

Tags: python-3.x, bucles

Tengo una archivo txt con unas 13000 líneas, las estoy importando y cuando quiero hacer un bucle para armar un archivo con la información reordenada como necesito, no logro que funcione.

La información del archivo es similar a esta (la parte con el número de línea es un añadido para referencia, no está originalmente en el fichero):

```
Linea 0:    A     213992,"A     114416","05/01/2021","19/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", \n
Linea 1:    A     114416,"Nombre 1                     ","*                                                 ","Address 1                     ","CAPITAL                       ","4682551534                     "," 74","F","1041","*                                                 ","   0","          ","     ","17/01/2013","17/01/2013","1202","1505254500070100                ","DNI", \n
Linea 2:    C,"37111662        ","01/05/1938","*                             ","2","*      ", \n
Linea 3:    G   
Linea 4:    A     213992,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 5:    13
Linea 6:     1      475I 1
Linea 7:     2      941I 1
Linea 8:     3      190I 1
Linea 9:     4      192I 1
Linea 10:    5      412I 1
Linea 11:    6     4811I 1
Linea 12:    7      865I 1
Linea 13:    8      867I 1
Linea 14:    9      902I 1
Linea 15:   10     8298I 1
Linea 16:   11      546I 1
Linea 17:   12      711I 1
Linea 18:   13      120N 1
Linea 19:   A     213993,"A     129320","05/01/2021","12/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 20:   A     129320,"Nombre 2                   ","*                                                 ","Address 2              ","CAPITAL                       ","4601555620  11531906         "," 73","F","   0","DNI 5564842                                       ","   0","          ","     ","05/01/2021","05/01/2021","1005","1504600761690600                ","DNI", 
Linea 21:   C,"569456742        ","11/10/1947","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 22:   G   
Linea 23:   A     213993,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 24:   12
Linea 25:    1      475I 1
Linea 26:    2      653I 1
Linea 27:    3      746I 1
Linea 28:    4      133I 1
Linea 29:    5      192I 1
Linea 30:    6      362I 1
Linea 31:    7      412I 1
Linea 32:    8     4811I 1
Linea 33:    9      546I 1
Linea 34:   10      902I 1
Linea 35:   11      948I 1
Linea 36:   12      120N 1
Linea 37:   A     214012,"A     129321","04/01/2021","18/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 38:   A     129321,"Nombre 3                   ","*                                                 ","Address 3               ","CAPITAL                       ","1123101950                    "," 86","F","   0","DNI 16561081                                      ","   0","          ","     ","04/01/2021","04/01/2021","1005","1505370046050100                ","DNI", 
Linea 39:   C,"16561       ","02/03/1934","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 40:   G   
Linea 41:   A     214012,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 42:   11
Linea 43:    1      475I 1
Linea 44:    2      192I 1
Linea 45:    3      297I 1
Linea 46:    4      412I 1
Linea 47:    5     4811I 1
Linea 48:    6      546I 1
Linea 49:    7      865I 1
Linea 50:    8      866I 1
Linea 51:    9      867I 1
Linea 52:   10      500I 1
Linea 53:   11     8298I 1
Linea 54:   A     214013,"A     125271","04/01/2021","13/01/2021","N","E","1005"," 136                          "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 55:   A     125271,"Nombre 4                  ","*                                                 ","Address 4                 ","CAPITAL                       ","4605-5813                     "," 69","M"," 136","DNI 6151369                                       ","   0","          ","     ","27/10/2017","27/10/2017","1005","1506000320150300                ","DNI", 
Linea 56:   C,"61546369        ","01/11/1948","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 57:   G   
Linea 58:   A     214013,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 59:   2
Linea 60:    1      412I 1
Linea 61:    2      500I 1
```

De la linea 0 necesito el elemento 0 y 2, de la linea 1 el campo 1, de la linea 2 el campo 16 a eso le concatene el 475 de la l6.esto lo tiene que hacer la cantidad de veces que dice la linea 5.

Ahi tiene que empezar de nuevo con el proceso en la linea 19 (que pasaria a ser la 0) y asi recorrer las 13000 lineas...

El resultado tendria que ser:

```
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,475
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,941
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,190
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,192
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,412
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,4811
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,865
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,867
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,902
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,8298
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,546
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,711
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,120
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 2                     ","*,475
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 2                     ","*,653
A213992,05/01/2021,070100      ,  ,Nombre 2                     ","*,746
```

Pero **Nombre 1** deberían ser unas 13 líneas (q es es variable, y es el que define la cantidad de líneas a imprimir por Nombre), ahí debería saltar a **Nombre 2** recalculando el `r0` (la linea inicial) y poniendo las las subcadenas de las primeras 3 líneas concatenadas con las q líneas que siguen.

Seguramente hay un forma mas facil de hacerlo que el bucle que hice yo y no funciona, y que es el siguiente:

```
with open ("E:\SkyDrive\A Files\A Files\LACVI\Datos LABSYS\PROT2101 test - COPY.txt", "r") as filename:

   lines = filename.readlines()

cantidad=len(lines)  


r0 = 0
q = int(lines[r0+5])
t = r0 + 6
print (q , t)

while r0 < r0+q+t:

   linea1 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   linea2 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+5
   linea3 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea3[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea4 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea4[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea5 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea5[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea6 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea6[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea7 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea7[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea8 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea8[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea9 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea9[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea10 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea10[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea11 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea11[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea12 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea12[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea13 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea13[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea14 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea14[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea15 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea15[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea16 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea16[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea17 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea17[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea18 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea18[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea19 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea19[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea20 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea20[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea21 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea21[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea22 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea22[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea23 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea23[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea24 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea24[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea25 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea25[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea26 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea26[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea27 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea27[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea28 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea28[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea29 = lines[r0]
   r0 = r0+1
   print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea29[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea30 = lines[r0]
  r0 = r0+1
  print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea30[4:12].strip(), sep=",")
linea31 = lines[r0]
  print(linea1[1:13].replace(" ", ""),linea1[31:41],linea2[342:354],linea2[354:356],linea2[16:50].rstrip(),linea31[4:12].strip(), sep=",")

   r0=q+7
   print(r0)
   break'''
```

No se si hay una forma de crear las líneas a imprimir que sea mas fácil (por ahora es la que encontré), estoy recién empezando y no entiendo porque el bucle no funciona.

Comment: hola,1) La primera parte es un fragmento del archivo de texto, abajo lo pongo con numero de lineas. 2) La salida no es lo que espero, abajo aclaro lo que quisiera que saliera. 3) Es que tiene que extraer info de cada linea, con el comienzo de la linea 0 y 1 ( hasta que llega al final del bucle, y ahi empezar con el campo que sigue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que he entendido lo que buscas, pero la información que das en la pregunta es erróna o incompleta, porque usandola no me sale exactamente lo que muestras que debería salir.

He tenido que retocar algunos de los índices que usas en los *slices*, pues se ve que tu fichero de entrada contiene algún carácter más (o menos) de lo que muestras en el ejemplo, quizás algún espacio por la izquierda. En todo caso, a partir del código que te doy no debería resultarte difícil adaptarlo a tu caso real.

La idea es la siguiente:

- El programa principal usa un bucle en el que en cada iteración lee 6 líneas del fichero, y saca de la última línea leida un valor N, que usa para leer también las N líneas siguientes.

  Para hacer esto hago un bucle `for linea in fichero`, pero dentro del bucle hago `next(fichero)` para leer una línea más cada vez que lo necesito. Por eso cada iteración del bucle acaba leyendo 6+N líneas.
- Las 6 primeras líneas las guarda en una lista, las N siguientes en otra.
- Estas dos listas se las pasa a una función, que es la que hace el "trabajo sucio" de extraer de cada una de esas líneas lo campos que te interesan, y usarlos para componer con ellos N líneas en la salida

El uso del bucle, de las listas y de la función simplifica enormemente el código evitando todas las repeticiones.

Queda así:

```
def procesar(l, extra):
  """Funcion que recibe las 6 primeras líneas del grupo en la lista l
  y las N lineas siguientes en la lista extra, y que extrae de estas
  lineas la información relevante para componer la salida"""

  datos = []                       # Lista con los campos a mostrar en una línea
  datos.append(l[0][1:13].replace(" ", ""))  # A213992
  datos.append(l[0][31:40])                  # fecha
  datos.append(l[1][341:352])                # 070100
  datos.append(l[1][353:355])                # ??
  datos.append(l[1][15:49].rstrip())         # Nombre 1...
  datos.append("")                           # A sustituir en cada linea
  
  for n in extra:
    datos[-1] = n[4:12].strip()  # Sustituimos el último campo
    print(",".join(datos))       # imprimimos la línea resultante


# PROGRAMA "PRINCIPAL"

with open("tu-fichero.txt") as f:
  # Aparentemente iteramos por las líneas del fichero, pero en realidad
  # cada iteración de este bucle es por un bloque de 6+N lineas
  for line in f:
    l = [line]                            # guardar primera linea del bloque
    l.extend(next(f) for i in range(5))   # leer y guardar las 5 líneas siguientes
    numero = int(l[5])                    # Extraer N de la última línea leida
    extra = [next(f) for i in range(numero)] # leer y guardar las N lineas siguientes

    # Pasar las líneas leidas a la función que las procesa
    procesar(l, extra)
```

Y lo que me sale a mi (no es exactamente igual a lo que tú pones, pues me temo como dije antes que mi fichero de entrada no es exactamente igual al tuyo) es lo siguiente:

```
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,475
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,941
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,190
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,192
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,412
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,4811
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,865
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,867
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,902
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,8298
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,546
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,711
A213992,5/01/2021,070100     ,  ,Nombre 1                     ","*,120
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,475
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,653
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,746
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,133
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,192
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,362
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,412
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,4811
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,546
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,902
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,948
A213993,5/01/2021,           ,,",Nombre 2                   ","*,120
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,475
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,192
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,297
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,412
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,4811
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,546
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,865
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,866
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,867
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,500
A214012,4/01/2021,           , ",Nombre 3                   ","*,8298
A214013,4/01/2021,           ,  ,Nombre 4                  ","*,412
A214013,4/01/2021,           ,  ,Nombre 4                  ","*,500
```

Comment: Funciona Genial!!!, hice unos cambios en los campos a mostrar del archivo original y anda perfecto!!!
Esto de aprender esta bueno, ahora voy a ver bien como lo hiciste para entender el proceso.
Te agradezco mucho.

Comment: Perfecto! No dudes en preguntar cualquier cosa que no te quede clara.

Comment: Perdona mi atrevimiento, pero si quisiera que aparte de agregar N[4:12] en cada linea, tambien agregue N[14:15], tendria que agregarle una variable a la funcion? o todo se podria incluir en Extra? Tendria que quedar A21....,...,475,1 y asi sucesivamente. Estoy viendo como agregar ese campo (que en el archivo descubri que no siempre es 1). Gracias!

Comment: creo que lo entendi bien, ahi le agregue  **' datos[-1] = (n[4:12].strip() + "," + n[14:15])'** y funciona bien. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Bien, iba a sugerirte otro enfoque, añadiendo a la lista `datos` otro elemento más (inicialmente cadena vacía también), para luego en el bucle asignar `datos[-2]` (que sería el penúltimo elemento) y `datos[-1]` (que sería el último), y así evitar la concatenación "a mano" de dos campos y la coma. Pero tu enfoque también funciona si lo prefieres.

Comment: @abufalia un consulta, cambiaron el archivo y ahora los datos no tiene los mismo rangos, se pueden utilizar un slicing por el lugar que ocupa en la linea considerando que cada valor esta entre "" y separado por comas (", "). Gracias